Insertar y modificar id de usuario que inserta y/o actualiza
Tengo las siguiente tablas en MSSQL Server.

EF Las mapea así:

namespace My.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class My_Services_N01
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public My_Services_N01()
        {
            this.My_Quotes_N01 = new HashSet<My_Quotes_N01>();
        }
    
        public int id_service { get; set; }
        public string name_service { get; set; }
        public string content_service { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> deleted_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> active_service { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<My_Quotes_N01> My_Quotes_N01 { get; set; }
        public virtual My_Users_N01 My_Users_N01 { get; set; }
        public virtual My_Users_N01 My_Users_N011 { get; set; }
        public virtual My_Users_N01 My_Users_N012 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace My.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class My_Users_N01
    {
       

 [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public My_Users_N01()
        {
            this.My_Services_N01 = new HashSet<My_Services_N01>();
            this.My_Services_N011 = new HashSet<My_Services_N01>();
            this.My_Services_N012 = new HashSet<My_Services_N01>();
        }
    
        public int id_user { get; set; }
        public string username_user { get; set; }
        public string password_user { get; set; }
        public string name_user { get; set; }
        public string last_name_user { get; set; }
        public string mail_user { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> active_user { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> deleted_at { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_user_created { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_user_updated { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_user_deleted { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ICollection<My_Services_N01> My_Services_N01 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<My_Services_N01> My_Services_N011 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<My_Services_N01> My_Services_N012 { get; set; }
    }
}

Cuando se crea un nuevo registro, el campo id_user_created debe ser el usuario que está logueada (obtenerlo ya lo tengo), cuando el servicio se actualiza, el campo id_user_updated se debe llenar.
Regularmente lleno así los datos a insertar:
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "name_service,content_service")] `My_Services_N01 My_Services_N01)`
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            My_Services_N01.active_service = true;
            My_Services_N01.created_at = DateTime.Now;
            db.My_Services_N01.Add(My_Services_N01);
           
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    return View(My_Services_N01);
}

Pero no puedo llenar la propiedad id_user_created, porque no me aparece (como una propiedad) dentro de la clase My_Services_N01. Lo mismo me pasa con la actualización.
¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias de antemano
